# SwiftUI - Create a filesystem tree view from a list of paths

Tags: swift, listview, swiftui, directory, treeview

I have a list of paths, for example a list parsed from the 'ls -R' stdout into an array, how can I create a very simple tree view list with that?

I am still learning swift, I can't figure out how to create the data structure necessary to populate a List view with children.

Comment: `struct SomeType { ... var children: [SomeType] ... }` for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Moved this from the user's question to an answer:*

Eventually I came up with this solution:

Create a Class for the items to display in the tree

```swift
class TreeItem: Identifiable{
    
    let Id = UUID()
    let Name: String
    var isExpanded = false
    var Children: [TreeItem] = [] //for subentries

    init(name: String, children: [TreeItem] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
    }
}
```

Create a View for the tree

```swift
struct TreeItemView: View {
    @State var item: TreeItem

    var body: some View {
        DisclosureGroup(
            isExpanded: $item.isExpanded,
            content: {
                if !item.Children.isEmpty {             
                    ForEach(item.Children) { child in
                        if (child.Children.isEmpty){
                            Text(child.Name))
                        }else{
                            TreeItemView(item: child)    
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            label: {
                Text(item.Name)
            }
        )
    }
}
```

And here is the function returning a nested array of type TreeItem from a list of paths

```swift
func parsePaths(PathList: [String]) -> [TreeItem]{
    let rootFolder = TreeItem(name: "root") //create startpoint
    
    PathList.removeAll { $0.isEmpty } //remove empty lines

    for path in PathList{

        let components = path.split(separator: "/").map(String.init) //split path in components by '/''
        var currentFolder = rootFolder //set root folder

        for component in components {

            if let existingFolder = currentFolder.Children.first(where: { $0.name == component }) { 
                currentFolder = existingFolder
            } else {
                let newFolder = TreeItem(name: component)
                currentFolder.Children.append(newFolder)
                currentFolder = newFolder 
            }
            
        }
    }

    return rootFolder.Children
}
```

Here is the main view with some sample data:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var content:[TreeItem] = [] //initialize the content var

    var body: some View {
        Button("Show"){
            content = parsePaths(PathList: [
                "/FolderA/file.a",
                "/FolderA/FolderAA/file.aa",
                "/FolderB/FolderBB/FolderBBB/file.bbb",
                "/FolderB/file.bbb",
                "/FolderA/file.a1"
            ])
        }
        List{
            ForEach(content, id: \.Id){item in
                    TreeItemView(item: item)
                }
        }
    }
}
```